# How to apply CSS for all similar elements simultaneously on an event

Tags: jquery

I have a section where there are many 5 textareas (number can change) .If i blur out of a text area i have to apply the  CSS to all the texts simultaneously using same function in JQuery. My thought is 
get all the  ids and apply the CSS. Is this correct way to do or is there any alternative

```
<div>
 <textarea id="libname"class="Text"></textarea>
<textarea id="bioname"class="Text"></textarea>
<textarea id="labname"class="Text"></textarea>
<textarea id="subjctname"class="Text"></textarea>
<textarea id="miscname"class="Text"></textarea>

</div>

<script>

    ???$(".ids").applycss();
</script>
```

Comment: why not use class instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the class you have..

```
$(".Text").css({ do css stuff });
```

And if you want this on `.blur()`

```
$(".Text").blur(function() {
    //if you want to apply css to all textareas, target them all
    $(".Text").css({ do css stuff });

    //if you want to edit the textarea you just modified, use this
    $(this).css({ do css stuff });
});
```

`.css()` API reference: http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 1):

Use [jQuery .css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

```
$('textarea.Text').css(/*whatever you want*/);
```

Answer (score 0):

I thinks you should define all style in class, and user `addClass()`/`removeClass()`/`toggleClass()` function of jquery in `blur event`